# How do I view a Custom Object on Salesforce1 using the Lightning Record Page I have defined for it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, custom-object, lightning, lightning-experience

I've spent a lot of time digging into this, and if there's a solution, it is eluding me. Here are the facts:

1. I have a Custom Object.
2. I have defined a Lightning Record Page for it (Flexipage under the hood), which contains some custom Lightning Components. It is the default View for my Custom Object. This works **great** on the desktop Lightning Experience.
3. In Salesforce1, I want to be able to navigate to the default view of one of these Custom Object records and see it using the Lightning Record Page.

My understanding/belief was that one big advantage of Lightning was that it would give us painless re-use between Desktop and Mobile settings, but when I navigate to a Custom Object using "`sforce.one.navigateToSObject()`" on Salesforce1, I am always presented with the Salesforce-generated default object view rather than my custom Lightning Record Page.

I have been attempting a workaround of this by forwarding to a Visualforce page and manually instantiating the Lightning Components with JavaScript, but that is pretty painful by comparison.

Is there something I'm missing here? How do we get our custom Lightning Record Pages to show up in Salesforce1 when we link to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce1 does not support Lightning Pages right now. The record pages still rely on the classic page layout. You can create your own Lightning Component wrapping up all the components you need and add a navigation tab for Salesforce1, but then you will have to built everything from scratch (Lightning Data Service will help you, though)

Also related to this post:
[Lightning component in record detail page salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178231/lightning-component-in-record-detail-page-salesforce1/178528#178528)

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue recently. Finally came to the conclusion that the Lightning record page has no impact on Salesforce1 layout. When creating a Lightning record page, there is no option for mobile preview, while this option exists if you're trying to create a new Lightning App. I hope Salesforce makes it truly responsive in a future release.